# Simplifying $(A-B^c)∪(B∩(A∩B)^c)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm looking to use laws of set algebra to simplify:

$(A-B^c)∪(B∩(A∩B)^c)$

But I'm currently stuck on what I should do.

= $(A-B^c)∪(B∩(A^c∪B^c))$ (De Morgan's)

= $(A-B^c)∪((B∩A^c)∪(B∩B^c))$ (Distributive Law)

= $(A-B^c)∪(B∩A^c)$ (Intersection with Compliment)

And from here, I'm stuck. If I draw up a Venn Diagram, I can see that the simplified expression would just be $B$, but I'm currently stuck on how to get there. I've tried turning $(B∩A^c)$ to $B - A$, but that didn't seem to help me much.

Comment: Are $A, B\subseteq X$?

Comment: Hi, the question doesn't specify any specific relations for A and B, so I'm not sure.

Comment: $A-B^c=A \cap B$

Comment: Thanks. I completely missed that, and can now apply distributive law which helped me finish the question.

Comment: Well, but where do you build the complement of $B$?

Answer (score 2):

We have $$(A-B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c)=(A\cap B)\cup(B\,\,\text\ A)=B$$

Answer (score 0):

$(A−B^c)∪(B∩(A∩B)^c)$

First go with **De-Morgan's**:
$B ∩ (A ∩ B)^c$ = $B ∩ (A^c ∪ B^c)$

Applying **Distributive Law**, $B ∩ (A^c ∪ B^c)$ = $(A^c ∩ B) ∪ (B ∩ B^c)$ = $(A^c ∩ B)$ **- (1)**

As,  $A - B$ = $A ∩ B^c$. Therfore, $A - B^c$ = $A ∩ B$ **-(2)**

**Using (1)&(2),**

$(A ∩ B) ∪ (A^c ∩ B)$ = $(A ∩ A^c) ∪ B$ = $B$